# When is the quotient map of L(X) to its homotopy class of loops a fibration.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fibration

Let $L(X)$ be loop space of $X$ which is path connected surface (and its universal cover is contractible and $\pi_n=0$ for $n >1$ this details i'm giving as i'm working on such surface.), let $a$ and $b$ be two equivalence class of $L(X)$.

In class $a$ we identify the loops with its based loop homotopy class and name it $L(X)/a$. That is two loops are in same class if if they have based loop homotopy between them.

In class $b$ we identify loops with its conjugacy classes and all its based loop homotopy classes and name it $L(X)/b$. That is two loops $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are in same class if we can find loop $\gamma$ such that $[\gamma*\alpha*\bar\gamma]=[\beta]$ all this loops have same based point.

So we have $f : L(X) \rightarrow L(X)/a$

and we have $g : L(X) \rightarrow L(X)/b$

So my question is will this two maps be Fibration?

Comment: Both of the quotients you define are discrete, and any surjection to a discrete space is a fibration.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan How is the quotient space discrete?